# Javascript implementation of find all links in selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I have the below Selenium code in Java. How can it be implemented in JavaScript?

```
package practiceTestCases;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FindAllLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/");
        java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println(links.size());

        for (int i = 1; i <= links.size(); i = i + 1) {
            System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try it yourself first. then if you are getting some difficulty tell us.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
var links, n, i, link, linkText;

links = document.links;
n = links.length;
console.log(n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  link = links[i]; 
  linkText = (link.textContent || link.innerText).trim();
  console.log(linkText);
}
```

Comment: Where does the variable document get defined and set.

Comment: It's an existing variable of the browser, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp My code can be run in the console of the browser. In case of Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, you can open the console by pressing F12, and selecting the "Console" item. In non-browser-related JavaScript engines, like Node.js, Mozilla Rhino or Oracle Nashorn, there is no `document` variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking to run the code in node.js so I may have to find anther solution.